# Properties of nested static class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this nested static class

```
public static class UserRoles
{
    public static class Administrator
    {
        public static string Code => "ADMIN";
        public static string Title => "Administrator";
    }

    public static class ClientUser
    {
        public static string Code => "CU";
        public static string Title => "Client User";
    }

    public static class Driver
    {
        public static string Code => "DR";
        public static string Title => "Driver";
    }
}
```

I am trying iterating over the properties of `UserRoles` but failed miserably. I've tried using `System.Reflection` which i think is the only suitable approach for the problem.

I've already tried using `GetFields` with bindings and `GetProperties` but unfortunately it is not working.

```
var fields = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

I've checked other questions already but i don't find any that is specific to this very basic and common case. Please let me know if this is a duplicate of anything.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Please, share what have you tried

Comment: UserRoles has no properties, only nested classes

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski you can read the whole question which states how i was placing the value on the `fields` variable

Comment: @Siege21x but you don't have fields, only inner classes

Comment: If you want to iterate over the properties of `UserRoles` class, first define those properties on that class. Currently all you have are nested types. Nested types and properties are not the same thing.

Comment: @atiyar Yep, i didn't realize that as i am new to C# which now i understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetNestedTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getnestedtypes?view=netframework-4.8) method for that

```cs
var userRoles = typeof(UserRoles).GetNestedTypes().SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties());
```

The code above returns enumeration of properties for every nested class in `UserRoles` class.

But if you want to store some information like set of keys and values, [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) is better choice, rather than static nested classes. Have a look at example below

```cs
public enum UserType
{
    Administrator,
    ClientUser,
    Driver
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
...
var roles = new Dictionary<UserType, UserInfo>
{
    { UserType.Administrator, new UserInfo { Code = "ADMIN", Title = "Administrator" } },
    { UserType.Driver, new UserInfo { Code = "DR", Title = "Driver" } }
    //and so on
};
//get admin title
var title = roles[UserType.Administrator].Title;
```

Comment: Let me try this one. Thanks a lot for this! Which i think this will work. I forgot that this is a `class` which equates to `type`.

Comment: This indeed works. Thanks a lot for this! Also, do you think what i am implying here is a bad practice? Enums doesn't support string value so i resorted to this. Sorry for the follow up question

Comment: @Siege21x Well, you can use a [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) for example, to store a collection of key/value pairs. User type is a key and user info is value

Comment: hi @pavel thank you for the suggestion. The reason why i'm trying it this way is i'm using it as an Enum and to make it an Object-Oriented approach, when comparing values on some feats.

Thanks though and i will have your suggestion considered on what i'm doing. thanks a lot for the help!